# Getting error on category list page - Magento2

Tags: magento2

**Getting error on category list page:**

The request query and filters aren't set. Verify the query and filters and try again.

> FYI, I have installed Mageplaza layered navigation extension and Mirasvit search extensions
>
> Error I am facing
> 1 exception(s):
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Search\Request\EmptyRequestDataException): The request query and filters aren't set. Verify the query and filters and try again.

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Search\Request\EmptyRequestDataException): The request query and filters aren't set. Verify the query and filters and try again.
#0 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/Search/Request/Builder.php(143): Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Cleaner->clean(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/melj/app/code/Mirasvit/Search/Model/Index/Searcher.php(129): Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Builder->create()
#2 /var/www/html/melj/app/code/Mirasvit/Search/Model/Index/Searcher.php(144): Mirasvit\Search\Model\Index\Searcher->getQueryResponse()
#3 /var/www/html/melj/app/code/Mirasvit/Search/Index/Magento/Catalog/Category/Index.php(93): Mirasvit\Search\Model\Index\Searcher->joinMatches(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection), 'e.entity_id')
#4 /var/www/html/melj/app/code/Mirasvit/Search/Model/Index/AbstractIndex.php(147): Mirasvit\Search\Index\Magento\Catalog\Category\Index->buildSearchCollection()
#5 /var/www/html/melj/app/code/Mirasvit/Search/Service/IndexService.php(41): Mirasvit\Search\Model\Index\AbstractIndex->getSearchCollection()
#6 /var/www/html/melj/app/code/Larson/Search/Block/Result.php(240): Mirasvit\Search\Service\IndexService->getSearchCollection(Object(Mirasvit\Search\Model\Index))
#7 /var/www/html/melj/generated/code/Larson/Search/Block/Result/Interceptor.php(115): Larson\Search\Block\Result->getSearchCollection(Object(Mirasvit\Search\Model\Index))
#8 /var/www/html/melj/app/code/Larson/Search/Block/Result.php(309): Larson\Search\Block\Result\Interceptor->getSearchCollection(Object(Mirasvit\Search\Model\Index))
#9 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(675): Larson\Search\Block\Result->_afterToHtml('<div id="ln_ove...')
#10 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#11 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Larson\Search\Block\Result\Interceptor->___callParent('toHtml', Array)
#12 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Larson\Search\Block\Result\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#13 /var/www/html/melj/generated/code/Larson/Search/Block/Result/Interceptor.php(650): Larson\Search\Block\Result\Interceptor->___callPlugins('toHtml', Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Larson\Search\Block\Result\Interceptor->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('searchindex.res...')
#16 /var/www/html/melj/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('searchindex.res...')
#17 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('searchindex.res...')
#18 /var/www/html/melj/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('searchindex.res...', false)
#19 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('searchindex.res...', false)
#20 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#21 /var/www/html/melj/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#22 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#23 /var/www/html/melj/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#24 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#25 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#26 /var/www/html/melj/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#27 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#28 /var/www/html/melj/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#29 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#30 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#31 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#32 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#33 /var/www/html/melj/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#34 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(258): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#35 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#36 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#37 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#38 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#39 /var/www/html/melj/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#40 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#41 /var/www/html/melj/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#42 /var/www/html/melj/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#43 /var/www/html/melj/shop/en-US/index.php(43): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#44 {main}
```

Any Help will Appreciate!!

Comment: Please share error.

Comment: @Oscprofessionals I have edited issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a error on this following Paths:

```
#6 /var/www/html/melj/app/code/Larson/Search/Block/Result.php(240): Mirasvit\Search\Service\IndexService->getSearchCollection(Object(Mirasvit\Search\Model\Index))
```

Try to Check the Function: **`Mirasvit\Search\Service\IndexService->getSearchCollection`**

You can also try by comment of calling this function in path: `/var/www/html/melj/app/code/Larson/Search/Block/Result.php`

Hope this will help you!!